# Reusable form templates in Rails/Grails/Playframework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, grails, playframework

How can I do [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates) with Rails, Grails or Playframework?

What is Rails/Grails/Playframework equivalent for

```
{% for field in form %}
   <div class="fieldWrapper">
     {{ field.errors }}
     {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

?

Comment: I find it a little odd that you need to know how to do this in 3 completely different frameworks at once. I guess you're very busy, very curious, or very bored :)

Answer (score 2):

In Grails templates are used to store reusable chunks of content. A Grails template named
`_myTemplate.gsp` can be included in another page (GSP) using

```
<g:render template="myTemplate"/>
```

For the specific case of defining the markup of forms in a DRY fashion, there are a number of plugins. The most advanced/popular is probably [bean-fields](http://grails.org/plugin/bean-fields), but there is a [successor](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-fields) arriving soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with partials in Rails - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked two question, first one is about reusing a template in other template and second one is about iterating over an object.

In play framework, for first one you must use **[include](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/tags#include)** tag and for second **[list](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/tags#list)** tag.